# Subsites showing on the quick launch bar

Tags: quick-launch, permissions

I have created some subsites that only one person has access to.  When I log in as different people they see different quick launch sites.  Some see the subsites that they do not have access to some do not.  I would like for people to only see the sites that they have access to.  I am using 2007.  And I do not know much

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting because the Quick Launch control should apply security trimming to the control.  This would mean the logged in user should only see what they should have rights to see logged in.  My thought is that you have permissions that aren't correct.   I would revisit permissions.   Read only access for users would also make the links appear.  Perhaps we used all authenticated users and added to groups?  Just a thought.  Perhaps test different solutions with a test user.  See if they see links that you didn't give them access to.  If they do than something is very odd.